# Changing paragraph indentation in PowerPoint 2003

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2003

In a text box in PowerPoint 2003 when I create a paragraph the second through nth lines are right indented with respect to the first line.  I would like to set the indention to 0 (i.e., no indentation).

The text looks like this:

```
xxxxx
 xxxx
 xxxx
```

And I would like it to look like this:

```
xxxxx
xxxxx
xxxxx
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps:-

1. Enable the Rulers
2. Select the text box
3. Adjust the ruler from the top accordingly

   [image: Ruler Image]

Go through this **[About indent and tab settings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/about-indent-and-tab-settings-HP003074115.aspx)**